# iPython: 'no module named' ImportError

Tags: python, ipython

Windows: I have the Python package CVXOPT installed on my computer for the regular Python distribution, though not specifically with Anaconda, so it imports fine when I'm doing text editor/cmd python scripting. I tried installing CVXOPT with Anaconda, but that didn't work so I'm having to import the library directly when working with iPython.

My directory structure looks like:

```
C:
--Python27
----Lib
------site-packages
--------cvxopt
----------__init__.py
----------.....
```

The error occurs when I run this code in an iPython notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cvxopt')
import cvxopt
```

The error:

```
ImportError: No module named cvxopt
```

How can I fix this? Perhaps I'm appending the path incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining a path a bit too deep in your file tree. You need to add to `sys.path` the folder just before your module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages')

import cvxopt
```

Here, `cvxopt` can be found in the `site-packages` folder. If you add the `cvxopt` folder in the sys path, it'll search a module of that name in the folder itself and will not checked the base folder.

Answer (score 2):

Import the path which contains the `cvxopt` package.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages')

import cvxopt
```

Comment: That path is included by default. Also, \ is the escape character.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Only when running that install. OP is running a separate install.